# Create an auto login for umbraco cms

Tags: mysql, asp.net, umbraco

I'm trying to create an auto login for Umbraco cms.

Meaning, I have a website which wraps the cms, and i want users to be able to use it,

Without entering their login details when entering the umbraco cms.

I want to be able to this without sending back the umbraco auth cookie to the user.

Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Logically if you create your own maintenance pages and then use Umbraco's [Content Servcie](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management-v6/Services/ContentService) you could maintain an Umbraco website from an alternative maintenance system without ever bothering with the Umbraco pipeline.  So you can remove login or the use of cookies as you see fit.  You could use something like [Microsoft Dynamic Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee845452%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to help build the maintenance engine.

If you want to use the Umbraco back-office I believe you are committed to using the Umbraco workflow, which includes login & cookies.